# Convert PNG to JPG Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, writablebitmap

i have a PNG file and i would convert into JPG
The PNG is a large size(high resolution) (for example 30/40MB)

if i use this code receive a memory leak

```
using (var fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("1.png",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
{
    WriteableBitmap wb = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(fileStream);
}
```

How to?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code cannot work since you loaded a png file, but the method beneath accepts jpeg stream. You can do the following>

1. Open the png file with `OpenFile`
2. Load the file into a `BitmapImage`
3. Create a `WriteableBitmap` from that `BitmapImage`
4. Save the created `WriteableBitmap` as a jpeg file using the SaveJpeg extension method.

Comment: if my file is a large size BitmapImage works? receive memory leak

Comment: Maybe not, but then that problem is not easily solvable.